# В каких случаях ударение переходит на частицу "не"?

Tags: орфоэпия

В каких случаях ударение переходит на частицу "не"? Здесь переходит?

Примеры:
1."Думать не надо"
2. "Не пригодится"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ваших примерах, разумеется, нет ударения на "не".

Где ударение падает на эту частицу? Вот что приходит в голову:

- не в чем *(упрекнуть себя)*
- не за чем *(было стоять* — в очереди). Не в смысле "ни к чему", "бесполезно" — слитное написание.
- не за что *(было взяться* или просто *ответ на "спасибо")*
- не от чего *(было расстроиться)*
- не дал (возможно ударение на *не)*

Как видно, в большинстве случаев это словосочетания с предлогом и местоимением. Но и в этих случаях ударение может падать и не на частицу "не", например *не при чём.*